# Dynamically created table supposed to break if too long

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a simple Jquery code to call a bunch of AJAX ping methods to find out if the system modules are up. This is generating a table row-by-row on every AJAX call result. The table looks pretty simple.

[image]

Now my problem is that the number of callable methods is growing and it might end up in a lot of scrolling, so I thought i set:

```
body {
  max-height: 500px;
}
```

but the table won't break, and I still end up in scrolling a lot. Any Idea to solve this?

I replaced the method calls with a random OK/ERROR so [you can run it in JSFiddle here.](https://jsfiddle.net/ddan/a25pfvny/)

```
// instead of AJAX call result just append random result
for (i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    $( "#resultTable" ).append( '<tr><td> TestWS </td>' +   
      (Math.random()<.5  ?
          '<td class="ok"> OK </td></tr>' :
          '<td class="error"> ERROR </td></tr>'
       )
  );
}
```

This dummy JQuery code is not important, only an example to show the problem, what I am looking for is to make this table break if it's too long.

Any suggestions are welcome. Thanks!

Comment: Why use a table?  Why not simple <div> elements?  You could even add a column or two and make this visible on a single mobile page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another approach. Possibly flexbox is a better solution, but fwiw:

```js
// instead of AJAX call result just append random result
var pageHeight = 200, cnt=1, oldcnt=0;
var endStr = '';
for (i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
 $( "#div"+cnt ).find('table.resultTable').append( '\
 <tr><td> TestWS </td>' + 
      (Math.random()<.5  ?
          '<td class="ok"> OK </td></tr>' :
          '<td class="error"> ERROR </td></tr>'
       )
 );
 if ( $( "#div"+cnt ).find('table.resultTable').height() > pageHeight){
    oldcnt = cnt;
  cnt++;
  $( "#container").append('<div id="div'+cnt+'"><table class="resultTable"><tr><th>Service</th><th>Result</th></tr></table>');
 }
  
}
```

```css
body {width:100%;max-height: 200px;}
th, td{padding:2px;border:1px solid;xwidth:50px;}
.resultTable th{background-color:#CCCCCC;font-weight:bold;}
.resultTable td.ok{background-color:#E1FFD8;font-weight:bold;}
.resultTable td.error{background-color:#FFB5B5;font-weight:bold;}
#container{width:100%;overflow:auto;border:1px solid orange;}
[id^=div]{max-width:120px;width:120px;float:left;margin-right:7px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
 <div id="div1">
  <table class='resultTable'>
    <tr><th>Service</th><th>Result</th></tr>
  </table>
 </div>
</div>
```

<kbd>[**jsFiddle Demo to play with**](https://jsfiddle.net/yw8r37er/2/)</kbd>

Answer (score 3):

For the easiest way would be is to use a scrollable vertical table. So, you'll have a scroll bar and you can scroll through the table data.

To create a scrollable vertical table. You'll need set the display and overflow property.

```
table {
  display: block;
  height: 200px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

For your convenience, I modified your [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a25pfvny/6/) so that you can have a look.

Comment: Good to put it with `tbody` instead of `table`.. **[`Demo`](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/a25pfvny/5/)**

Comment: Thanks, however this still needs scrolling.
I was thinking of something like seeing more it in more columns.
Something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/ddan/a25pfvny/7/

Comment: Modified the code that you suggested :) @GuruprasadRao

Answer (score 3):

So far one of the best options to use seems to be this:

Putting the table in a container and setting:

```
#container {
    column-count:3;
    -moz-column-count:3;
    -webkit-column-count:3;
}
```

So it shows the table in multiple columns without much (or no) scrolling needed.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ddan/a25pfvny/7/)

Any backdraws or major browser compatibility issues?

Comment: **Explorer** and **Edge** does not same to break between columns, which can be a bit annoying but works good for an example like this. **Firefox** won't break table into multiple columns at all, so that leaves scrolling in case of FF. In **Chrome** it works perfectly.

Comment: Not perfect support across browsers, but a super-elegant solution. If it's just for you, that might be good enough. Otherwise, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative.  You can use the tools from jQuery mobile to create a nice feature: collapsible headers.  That way your users can isolate specific test results in logically arranged groupings.

[image: collapsible headers with jQuery mobile]

Click / press the header to toggle visibility of the content beneath.

You can organize things just the way you need them.

```
<script src="http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.0/css/themes/default/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.css" />

<style type="text/css">

    li div { padding: 2px; border: 1px solid; float: left; width: 150px }

    .ui-collapsible-content .ui-filterable{ display: none; }

    li { background-color: #CCCCCC; font-weight: bold; }

    li div.ok { background-color: #E1FFD8; font-weight: bold; }

    li div.error { background-color: #FFB5B5; font-weight: bold; }

    .ui-li-static.ui-collapsible > .ui-collapsible-heading { margin: 0; }

    .ui-li-static.ui-collapsible { padding: 0; }

    .ui-li-static.ui-collapsible > .ui-collapsible-heading > .ui-btn { border-top-width: 0; }

    .ui-li-static.ui-collapsible > .ui-collapsible-heading.ui-collapsible-heading-collapsed > .ui-btn, .ui-li-static.ui-collapsible > .ui-collapsible-content { border-bottom-width: 0; }
</style>

<div data-role="collapsible" data-theme="b" data-content-theme- "b">
    <h2>First Category</h2>
    <ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true">
        <li><div class="title">TestWS1</div>
            <div class="ok"> OK </div>
        </li>
        <li><div class="title">TestWS2</div>
            <div class="error"> ERROR </div>
        </li>
        <li><div class="title">TestWS3</div>
            <div class="ok"> OK </div>
        </li>
        <li><div class="title">TestWS4</div>
            <div class="error"> ERROR </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div data-role="collapsible" data-theme="b" data-content-theme- "b">
    <h2>Second Category</h2>
    <ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true">
        <li><div class="title">TestWS10</div>
            <div class="ok"> OK </div>
        </li>
        <li><div class="title">TestWS11</div>
            <div class="error"> ERROR </div>
        </li>
        <li><div class="title">TestWS12</div>
            <div class="ok"> OK </div>
        </li>
        <li><div class="title">TestWS13</div>
            <div class="error"> ERROR </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```